# Handrolled mailbox processor in c#, manual scheduling to threadpool

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I've been using TPL.DataFlow to solve this problem, but it turns out that DataFlow is too slow for my usecase.

So I've handrolled my own Mailbox implementation.
This works, but puts unnecessary pressure on the threadpool when there are no messages.

I'd like to schedule the "Run" handler in the "Post" method.
The run handler may however only be schduled once per run.
That is, I need to enforce a maximum degree of parallelism of 1.
So if the run is already scheduled, it may not be scheduled again.
This is very performance critical so if there is some lock free way to solve this, that would be awesome.

```
public class ConcurrentQueueMailbox : Mailbox
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Envelope> userMessages = new ConcurrentQueue<Envelope>();
    private ConcurrentQueue<Envelope> systemMessages = new ConcurrentQueue<Envelope>();

    private WaitCallback run = null;
    public ConcurrentQueueMailbox()
    {            
        run = new WaitCallback(_ =>
        {
            while (systemMessages.Count > 0)
            {
                Envelope envelope = null;
                if (systemMessages.TryDequeue(out envelope))
                {
                    this.OnNext(envelope);
                }
            }

            while (userMessages.Count > 0)
            {
                Envelope envelope = null;
                if (userMessages.TryDequeue(out envelope))
                {
                    this.OnNext(envelope);
                }
            }

            //this should be removed
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(run);
        });
        //this should be removed
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(run);
    }

    public override void Post(Envelope envelope)
    {
        if (envelope.Payload is SystemMessage)
        {
            systemMessages.Enqueue(envelope);
        }
        else
        {
            userMessages.Enqueue(envelope);
        }

        --need to re-schedule here --->    
        //I'd like to schedule this mailbox to run again
        //but it may not be scheduled more than one time concurrently
        //
        //I'm aware of TPL DataFlow etc, but they are far too slow
        //
        //?????
        //{
        //    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(run);
        //}
    }
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: What is wrong with BlockingCollection classes?

Comment: @MartinJames I assume by the name that they are blocking? I assume I need volatile bool flags and other fancy stuff to make this work w/o blocking/locking

Comment: Are you sure that it's Dataflow that's too slow and not that you're using it incorrectly? Also, if you're worries about the ThreadPool, why not just use a dedicated thread that blocks when there are no messages?

Comment: Use a boolean flag to indicate if the run method is running and check this flag on Post.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an attempt here, but I have no idea how safe this is nor if it is optimal in efficiency.

Feedback?

```
public class Mailbox
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Envelope> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<Envelope>();

    private int scheduled = 0;
    private volatile bool hasUnScheduledMessages = false;
    private WaitCallback run;

    public Mailbox ()
    {
        run = new WaitCallback(Run);
    }

    public void Run(object state)
    {
        Envelope tmp;
        while (queue.TryDequeue(out tmp))
        {
            //code to process each message
        }

        scheduled = 0;
        if (hasUnScheduledMessages)
        {
            hasUnScheduledMessages = false;
            Schedule();
        }
    }

    public void Post(Envelope m)
    {
        hasUnScheduledMessages = true;
        queue.Enqueue(m);
        Schedule();
    }

    private void Schedule()
    {
        //only schedule if we idle
        if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref scheduled, 1) == 0)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(run);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `scheduled = 0` I don't think this is guaranteed to work. That write isn't volatile.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I completely understood your problem but it seems like [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with its property `IsBusy` would be a fit here:

```
public class ConcurrentQueueMailbox : Mailbox
{
    // ...
    private BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public ConcurrentQueueMailbox()
    {
        _worker.DoDowr+=(sender, e) =>
        {
            // your code here...
        };
    }

    public override void Post(Envelope envelope)
    {
        if (envelope.Payload is SystemMessage)
        {
            systemMessages.Enqueue(envelope);
        }
        else
        {
            userMessages.Enqueue(envelope);
        }

        // Run only if not running already...
        if (!_worker.IsBusy)
        {
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That will not work AFAIK, the IsBusy can change from when the if statement evaluates it and ontil the post method exits. that would leave the mailbox unscheduled evn tough there is a message in it

Comment: What @RogerAlsing says, plus C# already has concurrent and blocking collections.